# segment begins with?

Tags: url, segments, parsing

Is there a way, WITHOUT PHP, to test if a segment begins with a value?
We send emails with shortened URLs and want to be able to parse the segments accordingly.

i.e.

```
http://www.oursite.com/20140709XXXYY
```

would need to redirect to

```
http://www.oursite.com/event/20140709XXXYY
```

Or, is there a way to do this in .htaccess?

Yes, they will always be the similar to the one above, plus, we may also have some like this:

```
http://www.oursite.com/agenda/20140709XXXYY
```

which would need to redirect to

```
http://www.oursite.com/Chuy/DownloadFile2.aspx?File=Q:\\AGENDAS\\20140709XXXYY.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to manage redirects using ExpressionEngine. You could do it with htaccess, yes, but it's really convenient to do it with EE.

Take a look at [**Detour Pro.**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro)

Since you have some redirects that are repetitive in nature, it's possible you could make use of Detour Pro's "Wildcard Redirect" or "Wildcard Redirect with Segment Replacement" feature.

If that's not quite right, or if you want an alternate see Anna's suggestion of [Router](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/router).

> Router will automatically include the correct template for you, based
>   on which of your regex patterns match the current URL.

Comment: see modifications

Comment: I think you're best off using Detour Pro.

Comment: We have 1000+ events per year and I don't want to have to manually setup the redirects, only redirect if the segment begins with '20'. Plus, there may also be a querystring with an email address that we use to log the person in at the same time.

Comment: Since you have some redirects that are repetitive in nature, it's possible you could make use of Detour Pro's "Wildcard Redirect" or "Wildcard Redirect with Segment Replacement" feature. If that's not quite right, or if you want an alternatie see @Anna's suggestion of [Router](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/router). "Router will automatically include the correct template for you, based on which of your regex patterns match the current URL."

Answer (score 1):

Two additional "routing" addons:

**Template Routes**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes

**Router**
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/router

Comment: Those won't work for our cases.

Comment: I think Router would work for you. What specifically makes that one seem not workable?